# Is it allowed to use same HVAC system for main living and auto garage areas?

Tags: hvac, usa, texas

I am building a new home and the HVAC provider/contractor has proposed a single, shared system to heat/cool both my main living and garage areas.  Proposed solution has separate returns, thermostats and duct/damper controllers for each area, although nothing would prevent both areas being engaged at same time.  Is this allowed, code-wise?

Home is in Texas, USA.

Comment: What does the code say?

Comment: mixing garage air with air going into the living areas seems risky,

Comment: Ignoring the code issues, ever change the oil in your garage? Do you really want that smell blown through the entire house?

Comment: I cannot believe any HVAC contractor would suggest the possibility of garage and home air being mixed. There are multiple reasons not to.

Comment: Allowed - probably. Smart - I don't think so. Then again, in this day and age, I'd be thinking (good) mini-splits for the whole shebang unless I was going to go ground-source for the heat pumps, and either makes having a head in the garage that does not move air to the house super-easy. And smart by my thinking.

Comment: my state does not allow residential ductwork to have an opening into a garage, ostensibly for fire risk.

Comment: In addition to fire there is a serious carbon monoxide danger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Certainly **IRC** includes section **M1601.6** titled "Independent Garage HVAC Systems" which states that

> Furnaces and air-handling systems that supply air to living spaces
> shall not supply air to or return air from a garage.

https://codes.iccsafe.org/content/IRC2018/chapter-16-duct-systems

According to https://up.codes/viewer/texas/irc-2015/chapter/16/duct-systems#16

That IS applicable/adopted without amendment (and the 2015 *.vs.* 2018 code language is unchanged) in Texas, so I'd find another HVAC contractor, pronto, personally. If they don't know the code in the state they operate in, what *else* are they screwing up?